# Background image inline css Set properly

Tags: html, css

I have set an background image to header tag (inline css - as each page has different image), i wanted to make the image to set properly to the header that the complete image will be fitted in the header section depending on the resolution without resizing the image.

```
<header class="header header-inverse" style="background-image: url(assets/solframes/\Web_graphics_OUTSOURCING_GOVERNANCE.png); background-position: inherit;" data-overlay="4">
```

you can have the demo at : http://sequentia.xyz/demo/people-analytics-productivity-improvement-software-tool

Comment: have you tried `background-position: fixed;`?

Comment: @boang3000 yes its not working

Comment: `background-size: cover` ?

Comment: can you create a fiddle? so that we can see what you have done?

Comment: as I can see in the demo, there is an extra class 'bg-fixed' in the header tag. If you want to make whole image visible and centered, remove 'bg-fixed' and add css background-size:cover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...hello please use `'background-attachment: initial;'` instead of `'background-attachment: fixed;'` or remove `'background-attachment'` property and also use `'background-size: cover;'`

Answer (score 0):

You can try `background-size: cover;` for the background to span the entire header.